# Finding the longitudes and latitudes within a perimeter using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, latitude-longitude

I'm using SQLalchemy to define my tables. These tables describe seismic events, which are arranged in Events, Origin, Magnitude, Real_Quantity and Time_Quantity. They are well to follow the standard of QuakeML. The Event table is relationship with Origin through .preferredOriginID and .publicID, Origin is relationship with Real_Quantity through .latitude_id and .id.

I want to find all longitudes and latitudes that are within a specified radius, but the problem is that both latitude and longitude are in the same Real_Quantity column and the Origin table is where specify which are different.

This is the code that I want to implement, but it is in MySQL

```
SELECT
    id,
    (
        acos(
            (
                cos(radians(37))
                * cos(radians(lat))
                * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122))
            )
          + (
                sin(radians(37))
                * sin(radians(lat))
            )
        ) * 3959
    ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

This is what I did, but only you can use the latitudes and I want to use the latitudes with longitudes

```
z = self.session.query(Event) \
    .join(Origin) \
    .join(RealQuantity, Origin.latitude) \
    .filter(
        Event.preferredOriginID == Origin.publicID,
        RealQuantity.id == Origin.latitude_id
    ) \
    .group_by(Event, Origin.latitude, RealQuantity.value) \
    .having(func.cos(RealQuantity.value) < 50)
```

Event:
id| publicID | preferredOriginID | preferredMagnitudeID | type |....

Origin:
id| publicID | time_id |latitude_id | longitude_id | depth_id |...

Real_Quantity:
id| value | ....

The Origin is just pointers, the values of this are in Real_Quantity

My models are:

```
class Event(Base):
__tablename__ = 'event'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
publicID = Column(String)

preferredOriginID = Column(String)
preferredMagnitudeID = Column(String)

type = Column(String)  
typeCertainty = Column(String)

creationInfo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('creation_info.id'))
creationInfo = relationship(CreationInfo, backref=backref('event', uselist=False))


class Origin(Base):
__tablename__ = 'origin'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
publicID = Column(String)

time_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('time_quantity.id'))
time = relationship(TimeQuantity, backref=backref('origin', uselist=False))

latitude_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('real_quantity.id'))
latitude = relationship(RealQuantity, foreign_keys=[latitude_id]
                        , backref=backref('origin_lat', uselist=False))

longitude_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('real_quantity.id'))
longitude = relationship(RealQuantity, foreign_keys=[longitude_id]
                         , backref=backref('origin_lon', uselist=False))

depth_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('real_quantity.id'))
depth = relationship(RealQuantity, foreign_keys=[depth_id],
                     backref=backref('origin_depth', uselist=False))

creationInfo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('creation_info.id'))
creationInfo = relationship(CreationInfo, backref=backref('origin', uselist=False))

event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('event.id'))
event = relationship('Event', backref=backref('origin', uselist=True))


class RealQuantity(Base):
__tablename__ = 'real_quantity'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
value = Column(Float)
uncertainty = Column(Float)
lowerUncertainty = Column(Float)
upperUncertainty = Column(Float)
confidenceLevel = Column(Float)
```

Comment: In the MySQL sample code, I presume (37, -122) is the search location?

Comment: No, 37 is latitud and -122 is longitude of circle center and 25 is the radius. (lat,lng) are locations that you want to find

Comment: Can you please post your models?  This will help.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution (yet), just some comments:

For every query, you are doing a complex calculation on every entry in the Origin table. As the number of entries increases, this will become very slow (computationally expensive).

Think of a circle `(x=lon, y=lat, r=distance)` projected on the globe. You can calculate min and max latitude easily; min and max longitude can also be done, although the math is quite a bit trickier.

If you have properly indexed the Origin table by latitude and longitude, you can do a very fast (computationally cheap) initial box-select on `min_lat <= lat <= max_lat and min_lon <= lon <= max_lon` which should trivially discard 99% of the entries (depending on radius and clustery-ness of the Origin points); remaining entries should have roughly an 80% chance of belonging to your desired data-set, and you only need to run the expensive calculation on the remaining entries.

I would strongly recommend writing this as a stored procedure.